# Configure RAID 1 on ThinkServer TS140

Tags: raid1, mirror, hotswap

I am setting up a server for a business, and one of the specifications that they have set is a RAID 1 configuration for the two drives in the machine (the OS will be installed on this mirror).  One of the mirrored drives will be in a hot swap bay, so that at the end of the day, he can take the bay drive out, put it in a safe, and put another drive in.  The two hot swappable drives will rotate each day.

I am trying to set this up on a Lenovo ThinkServer TS140, but have a two issues:

1. When I start the server up, I do not get a prompt to configure a RAID array.  I had worked with another server of the exact same model, and would get a prompt to hit CTRL+I to enter the RAID configuration utility.  Do I need to install something first?
2. I was wondering if this would be possible using the mainboard RAID (or given the fact that the mainboard never prompts for such), if I need a controller card for this?

The owner of the business says that his current server does this, so I'm going to head over there to examine the old one, but that won't be until 5PM.  I tried contacting Lenovo technical support, but 1) he insisted the option was there when it never prompted for such, and 2) also insisted that I needed Lenovo hard drives to make this work (with or without a controller card).

Thanks in advance.

2016.06.14 Edit:

It is exactly as he described it.  He has a FastTrak TX2300 and a RAID controller.  The drive bay and the internal drive both plug into the controller card, and he just yanks the drive at the end of the day.  I also asked how long he has been doing this, and he said "Just about 10 years."

As far as "Taking out a disk out of a RAID array is no replacement for a proper backup", I didn't say it was.  This is just what he wants to do.  I'm going to recommend he also use NovaBackup to an external hard drive, but this is one of his specifications.

Comment: You can't break a RAID-1 each day, each member will rebuild and such. You need a third HDD, to put like a acronis/system recovery on it

Comment: He did mention some other software; WebPAM.  However, the documentation reads like a RAID monitor, not management:

http://www.promise.com/media_bank/Download%20Bank/Manual/1_WebPAM%20User%20Manual%20v1.4.pdf

Comment: Bad idea. A solution that works 10 years ago, doesn't mean it will works forever. This method will works for old day 50GB disk. Around 500 GB, RAID 1 sync (with fast and new SAS controller, max 110Mbps ) will take at 1 hours++.   Enough to make backup to a backup server minus the risk of physical move around.

Comment: I stated that he has been doing this for 10 years to illustrate that some of the concerns brought up haven't really hindered his solution.  Yes, he has mentioned that it does take a few hours to rebuild, but has no issues other than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for question 1 on my post, I found that a BIOS setting was misconfigured.  I had to enter Devices > ATA Drive Setup > Configure SATA as - RAID.

As far as question 2, since I was able to set the drives up for RAID 1 in the Configuration Utility, I should be able to set it up how the buyer wants it.  We're going to recommend that he uses NovaBackup to make a backup image to a third drive, which he can rotate out in the hot swap bay.  If, however, he wants it set up the same way, that is the way we're going to do it.

Answer (score 5):

## No!

This is not a sane approach. At all. Taking out a disk out of a RAID array is no replacement for a proper backup. Among other things, you needlessly put yourself to the risk of a failed recovery due to a bad "primary" disk.

Comment: I agree, but it is how he described it, and how he wants it.  I'm hoping when I get a chance to actually look at his old server, that I'll see a more sane configuration.